# Make parent DIV enclose floating chid DIVs

Tags: html, css, height

I've been having trouble creating parent DIVs that encloses the floating child DIVs.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child1">content</div>    
    <div class="child2">content</div>
    <div class="child3">taller content</div>
</div>
```

...where `#parent` would expand vertically (with padding if it was styled that way) to accomodate `.child3.`  And If I added a border around `#parent` it would enclose all three child DIVs.

What's the best way to style this arrangement to ensure this behavior?

Looking for the best practice.

Comment: Bhesh, I'm clearing each new parent div, as I'm stacking divs one the page: one for the nav one for the slider, then another for three columns of content, then another for more content.  But when I do that and try to show a top and bottom border I see that the parent doesn't stretch to cover the child divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a "wrapper" div inside the parent, and a "clear: both" element in there as well. Check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yvVP8/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="child1">content</div>
        <div class="child2">content</div>
        <div class="child3">taller content lala lala lalal lala</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#parent {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
}

#wrapper .child1, #wrapper .child2, #wrapper .child3 {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 90px;
}

div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The extra `#wrapper` div isn't needed, you can use the pseudo element `:after` and style that element.
`#parent:after {content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}`

Comment: Correct, but `:after` is not supported in IE7 and earlier. If that's not an issue, then `:after` is just as good (or even better). [Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15)

Comment: Thanks guys.  Quick question: the extra divs, people always say avoid too many divs in your markup.  But it seems necessary to get what I'm looking for, unless I take a chance on breaking layouts on IE7 and earlier browsers.  Is it a big deal to have a few extra divs per page?

Comment: As long as it's necessary to get the result you want, an extra div or two isn't going to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
#parent {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

will do the job :

http://jsfiddle.net/XAbhY/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `float:left;` to the parent div.

It should force the parent's size/border to wrap all siblings.  Not sure if it's valid, but works for me.